# SQL report generate duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I am new to SQL report writing, trying to generate report from SQL tables but getting 3 duplicate rows against each desired rows in a result. However, the output data is as per my requirements. The entire code is given below kindly help me to resolve.

```
SELECT 
   v.dateaccessioned AS 'Date', v.barcode AS 'Acc. No.', w.title AS 'Title',
   w.author AS 'Author/Editor', concat_ws(' , ', o.editionstatement, 
   v.enumchron) AS 'Ed./Vol.',
   concat_ws(' ', o.place, o.publishercode) AS 'Place & Publisher',
   w.copyrightdate AS 'Year', o.pages AS 'Page(s)', s.name AS 'Source',
   v.itemcallnumber AS 'Class No./Book No.', concat_ws(', ₹', concat(' ',
   z.symbol, x.listprice), x.rrp_tax_included) AS 'Cost', concat_ws(' , ',
   r.invoicenumber, r.shipmentdate) AS 'Bill No. & Date', '' AS 'Withdrawn 
   Date', '' AS 'Remarks'

FROM biblioitems o
LEFT JOIN items v ON v.biblioitemnumber=o.biblioitemnumber
LEFT JOIN biblio w ON w.biblionumber=o.biblionumber
LEFT JOIN aqorders x ON x.biblionumber=o.biblionumber
LEFT JOIN currency z ON z.currency=x.currency
LEFT JOIN aqinvoices r ON r.booksellerid=v.booksellerid
LEFT JOIN aqbooksellers s ON s.id=v.booksellerid

WHERE v.barcode BETWEEN <<Accession Number>> AND <<To Accession Number>>
ORDER BY v.barcode ASC
```

Comment: then use distinct

Comment: Thanks, Can you please give an example through above code how and where to use "distinct"

Comment: I shared the answer with code below

Comment: They're not duplicates. They're just very similar

Answer (score 0):

If rows are identical Then you can use distinct keyword like  below :

```
SELECT distinct
v.dateaccessioned AS 'Date', v.barcode AS 'Acc. No.', w.title AS 'Title',
w.author AS 'Author/Editor', concat_ws(' , ', o.editionstatement, 
v.enumchron) AS 'Ed./Vol.',
concat_ws(' ', o.place, o.publishercode) AS 'Place & Publisher',
w.copyrightdate AS 'Year', o.pages AS 'Page(s)', s.name AS 'Source',
v.itemcallnumber AS 'Class No./Book No.', concat_ws(', ₹', concat(' ', 

z.symbol, x.listprice), x.rrp_tax_included) AS 'Cost', concat_ws(' , ', 

r.invoicenumber, r.shipmentdate) AS 'Bill No. & Date', '' AS 'Withdrawn 

Date', '' AS 'Remarks'

FROM biblioitems o
LEFT JOIN items v ON v.biblioitemnumber=o.biblioitemnumber
LEFT JOIN biblio w ON w.biblionumber=o.biblionumber
LEFT JOIN aqorders x ON x.biblionumber=o.biblionumber
LEFT JOIN currency z ON z.currency=x.currency
LEFT JOIN aqinvoices r ON r.booksellerid=v.booksellerid
LEFT JOIN aqbooksellers s ON s.id=v.booksellerid

WHERE v.barcode BETWEEN <<Accession Number>> AND <<To Accession Number>>
ORDER BY v.barcode ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried but still getting 3 same rows against each rows

Comment: There must be difference of any column's value. Show the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick and done. v.barcode is unique record so i just added

GROUP BY v.barcode

and getting only one rows against each record.

Answer (score -1):

Either you distinct or group by. In below code I used group by.

```
SELECT 
v.dateaccessioned AS 'Date'
, v.barcode AS 'Acc. No.'
, w.title AS 'Title'
, w.author AS 'Author/Editor'
, concat_ws(' , ', o.editionstatement,     v.enumchron) AS 'Ed./Vol.'
,    concat_ws(' ', o.place, o.publishercode) AS 'Place & Publisher'
,    w.copyrightdate AS 'Year', o.pages AS 'Page(s)', s.name AS 'Source'
,    v.itemcallnumber AS 'Class No./Book No.'
, concat_ws(', ₹', concat(' ',     z.symbol, x.listprice), x.rrp_tax_included) AS 'Cost'
, concat_ws(' , ', r.invoicenumber, r.shipmentdate) AS 'Bill No. & Date'
, '' AS 'Withdrawn Date'
, '' AS 'Remarks'

FROM biblioitems o
LEFT JOIN items v ON v.biblioitemnumber=o.biblioitemnumber
LEFT JOIN biblio w ON w.biblionumber=o.biblionumber
LEFT JOIN aqorders x ON x.biblionumber=o.biblionumber
LEFT JOIN currency z ON z.currency=x.currency
LEFT JOIN aqinvoices r ON r.booksellerid=v.booksellerid
LEFT JOIN aqbooksellers s ON s.id=v.booksellerid

WHERE v.barcode BETWEEN <<Accession Number>> AND <<To Accession Number>>
GROUP BY 
v.dateaccessioned 
, v.barcode 
, w.title 
,w.author 
, concat_ws(' , ', o.editionstatement, v.enumchron) 
,concat_ws(' ', o.place, o.publishercode) 
,w.copyrightdate 
, o.pages 
, s.name 
,v.itemcallnumber
, concat_ws(', ₹', concat(' ', z.symbol, x.listprice), x.rrp_tax_included) 
, concat_ws(' , ', r.invoicenumber, r.shipmentdate)
ORDER BY v.barcode ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried but still getting 3 same rows against each rows

Comment: What do you mean by "getting 3 same rows against each rows"? Can you share the query results, Will be helpful to figure out actual problem.

Comment: same contents in a rows i was getting 3 times i.e. 3 rows for similar data.